# Wave Impedance vs Characteristic Impedance

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, impedance, electromagnetic, wave

What is the physical difference between Wave Impedance and Characteristic Impedance? What are the meanings of these in a wave port in a simulator software?

Comment: Not much.;)...... they’re both the same computational parameters, not physical

Answer (score 2):

The wave or radiation impedance of an ***electromagnetic wave*** is defined as the ratio of its electric to magnetic field intensities.
So, in free space the value is 377Ohms  and in dielectric materials, the wave impedance is 377/n (n is the refractive index).
Concerning the characteristic impedance, it refers to ***impedance in electrical circuits*** (the transmission line : Z0).
Here it is the ratio of the amplitudes of voltage and current waves propagating along a line, travelling in one direction in the absence of reflections in the other direction.

Most of times, in HFSS or CST for example, Lumped Port can be used to feed  microstrip feed Lines (can approximate real feed and the port must be located inside the simulation volume). So Lumped Port doesn't calculate the field distribution but only excites a voltage at the Lumped Port location and calculates current then, extracts structure specifications. That's why you can set an impedance to it.

Contrary to Lumped Port, Wave Port can be assigned for coaxial cables, Waveguides...So it calculates field distribution (note that you can't define the port inside the simulation volume).

I don't know if it's clear but here is a quick explanation.
I think you can find more details about this on Youtube or Google.

Answer (score 0):

Characteristic impedance is the impedance of the line that is connected to a device. And wave impedance is the impedance of a wave propagating in the device. So you have the reflection coefficient is equal to
$$ \Gamma= \frac{z_w-z_c}{z_w+z_c}$$. It is useful concept to deal with, it works as in transmission lines